# asp.net web application in Visual Studio 2008 with dotnet framework 2 not working on windows 8 client machine

Tags: asp.net

I have developed an asp.net web application in Visual Studio 2008 
with dotnet framework 2.

I hosted this application.

I tried to run this application on client machine(through browser) 
which has windows 8, but my application failed to run.

Things i did to resolve the above issue:

On my client machine i installed dotnet framework 2.0, my application started 
working.
But as this is not a genuine soltion as i cant install the framework on all the client machines.

Now, again I uninstalled the dotnet framework 2.0 from the same machine, the application 
was still working fine(running through the browser)
If assume that some depandant files are not uninstalled by the Operating system itself.

Then i upgraded my application to framework 4.5. Still i found that application is not working
on windows 8.

So is there still some dependancy on framework 2.0? 
do i need to add some additional dlls when i host the application so that it runs on 
windows 8 without any dependancy on the system configuration?
Do i need to make any specific changes in the web.config?

Also note that, on the same client machine which as windows 8, i installed Visual Studio 2013,
have source code there, and when i run the same application through visual studio runtime, 
my application runs just fine.